# How to make an Profile implementation in Kotlin Android Studio with Firebase and get document value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

```
class Dados : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDadosBinding
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDadosBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        loadUserInfo()
        }
        private fun loadUserInfo() {
            val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
            ref.child(firebaseAuth.uid!!)
                .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        val email = "${snapshot.child("email").value}"
                        val name = "${snapshot.child("name").value}"
                        // set data
                        binding.userEmail.text = email
                        binding.userName.text = name
                    }
                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    }})}}
```

I want the userEmail get the email by Firebase

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?